# Responsive Header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I found this website: https://www.picmonkey.com/ and would like to learn how the responsive nav technique was accomplished. At full screen, the logo, icon-menu and sign up bars are evenly spaced out and as you shrink the screen to just before the menu goes full responsive, the three sections (logo, icon menu and sign up bar) keep an even percentage away from one another.

I've created a shell of the nav and was wondering, is this just a feature of having those items take up certain percentages of the screen or is it a simple margin-left/float?

```css
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#header
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 87px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
}

#header-fixedWidth
{
    width: 92%;
    min-height: 87px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#picMonkeyLogo
{
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: left;
}

#icon-menu
{
    min-height: 87px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 150px;
    
}

#icon-menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

#icon-menu ul li
{
    min-height: 87px;
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
}

#icon-menu ul li img
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
            <div id="header-fixedWidth">
                <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="picMonkeyLogo" id="picMonkeyLogo" />
                <div id="icon-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <img src="Images/iconMenu/edit.png" alt="editIcon" />
                            <p>Edit</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="Images/iconMenu/touchUps.png" alt="touchUpIcon" />
                            <p>Touch Up</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="Images/iconMenu/design.png" alt="designIcon" />
                            <p>Design</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="Images/iconMenu/collage.png" alt="collageIcon" />
                            <p>Collage</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just wondering if you are aware of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: I think it might be using the technique outlined here but I'm not 100% sure: https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/#article-header-id-5

Comment: @WinterSoldier Aware, but I was hoping to tangle with media queries a little more

Comment: @Michelle Thanks Michelle, I'll give this a try!